# GeoServer REST API: how to create an MBTiles datastore

Tags: geoserver, geoserver-rest-api

I want to create an MBTiles datastore using the REST API of GeoServer.

I was able to create a datastore for a shapefile using:

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain"
  -d "file:///data/shapefiles/rivers/rivers.shp"
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/rivers/external.shp
```

I didn't find any example for MBTiles files. So, I tried the following (after adding the MBTiles extension to my GeoServer):

```
curl -v -u admin:geoserver -XPUT -H "Content-type: text/plain"
  -d "file:///data/path/to/mbtiles/file.mbtiles"
  http://localhost:8080/geoserver/rest/workspaces/acme/datastores/rivers/external.mbtiles
```

But got the following return code:

```
400 Unsupported format: mbtiles
```

Can any body help me with the right way or a turn around way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The clue is in the error message - mbtiles is an unsupported [format](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html#extension) for the rest API.

To fix this you will need to [modify the code](http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/developer/) to support it or request a [commercial support provider](http://geoserver.org/support/) to do it for you.

Comment: Thanks Ian for your answer. I can write a code that create the datastore's and layer's XMLs, then put them in the Geoserver's data_dir, but the problem is that Geoserver must be restarted to read these new files, Is there a solution for that?

Comment: I wouldn't do that - messing with the internals of GeoServer's data directory with out going through the code is prone to causing issues sooner or later. If you have the code roll it into the code base please

Comment: Ok, you're right